# Count and divide distinct value pairs from multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'm new to SQL and having trouble looking for a query that can produce
the last output table.

Example table of what I have:

```
ID      Color
=============
0       red
0       red
0       blue
1       red
1       yellow
1       yellow
```

Now with this query I can produce this table

```
SELECT id, color, count(*) as num
from table group by id,color 

ID      Color      num    
=======================
0       red         2
0       blue        1
1       red         1
1       yellow      2
```

And with this query I can produce this table

```
SELECT id, count(*) as num
from table group by id

ID      num    
============
0        3
1        3
```

But I'm looking to have an output like this.
So I'm trying to figure out a way to combine those two above queries to 
produce this output table.

```
ID      Color      num    
=======================
0       red         0.667 = 2/3 
0       blue        0.333 = 1/3
1       red         0.333 = 1/3
1       yellow      0.667 = 2/3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `count` window function in dividing those values.

```
SELECT distinct id, color, 
1.0*count(*) over(partition by color,id)/count(*) over(partition by id) as num
from table
```